# Java: Authenticate user from JAAS protected Restful API (Jersey) on Glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, glassfish

I have implemented a `Restful` API for my simple application using `Jersey`, this API (Restful webservice) is protected by `JAAS` (Java Authentication and Authorization Service).

Now if user try to access a URL something like `example.com/api/user/info/1`, A popup(`BASIC`-Authentication) appears in browser to take input for username and password on successful login user is able to see the result (success).

so far so good.

Now I was thinking about the 3rd party application that will access my Restful web service. must authenticate before accessing any endpoint. (I know if an un-authenticated user will try to access my endpoint URLs JAAS will intercept that).

I am also aware that if I provide username and password in the request header, JAAS will automatically authenticate that as well.

**Confusions:**

***1*** - I do not want to embed username and password onto each request (I am not suer why, but I just don't want it (Please share your comments)) so that if I am accessing secure endpoint get authenticated automatically. I just want to authenticate a user and generate a token and then use that token in rest of the communication.

**2** - I want to provide some endpoint for 3rd party applications to deliberately initiate the authentication process.
`example.com/api/authenticate` but the username and password still in header. and when endpoint's relative method is called it extract username and password from that request's header. I am aware of 2 annotations `@QueryParam` and `@FormParam`, but I want something like `@HeaderParam`.
**Why?** I think that is more secure way. (Is that right?)

```
@Path("authenticate")
public String authenticate( ) {

}
```

**3** - I tried multiple techniques to login programmatically but none seems to work on `Glassfish`, so is it right its not possible on Glassfish? I am using Realm based JAAS.

**4** - I am looking for some way once I have authenticated the user prorgammatically, add some information to the session. and in any other request get that information from session. (I am using Jersey based classes for endpoints and EJBs for business logic) - I know in EJBs through context we can lookup principal and then from that we can retrive the user record from database etc. but is there any thing Jersey Endpoint classes can add to the session and get them back in any other endpoint class?

**5** - Is it enough for 3rd party application to save cookies returned by my Webservice and embed them in next request to have long lasting session for JAAS authenticated user (so that authentication process may not be required on each request)